# What does the に in でしょうに mean?

Tags: meaning, particle-に

Recently I was talking to a friend and the topic of credit cards came up. I asked my friend (xx) if they had a credit card:

> ところで、xxはクレジットカードを持ってる？

and got the following response:

> そりゃあ持っているでしょう**に**。

I'm not too sure what the に at the end means, but searching around the internet it seems to be related to のに. However, sentences that end with のに typically indicate disappointment/regret etc and I don't believe that was the case here. I found [this](https://hinative.com/ja/questions/60469):

> あなた、それくらい分かっているでしょうに。
>   You know that, don't you?
>   この場合の、don't you? に相当するのが、「でしょうに」です。

which seems close in meaning, but it doesn't feel like it's from のに. Any elucidation on this would be helpful.

Comment: `I asked my friend if they had a credit card` ← What were the exact words you used to ask that? IMHO, that would be the key for a productive answer. The reply sounds fairly nuanced; therefore, a good amount of context in the original Japanese would help a ton. A long explanation in English would not.

Comment: @l'électeur Added what I said when I asked..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 「そりゃあ持{も}っているでしょう**に**。」

For the majority of native speakers, this is **not** a *regular*, "calm/relaxed" way to say:

> "(Yes,) I have (a) credit card(s)."

That is why I asked above how exactly you asked your question that triggered the use of the highly nuanced and possibly emotional に-ending.

My first impression when I read this question before the edit was that the speaker was slightly irritated or surprised at your question -- "**Of course, I have a credit card.  Why would you even ask?**".  That could happen because credit cards are far more common in Japan than what the popular J-vloggers on YouTube seem to want you to believe.

According to [goo辞書](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/17288/meaning/m0u/%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB/), 「（よ）うに」 does the following:

> ★後悔・不満・非難・疑問・感動などを表わす。

That means "**expressing regret, dissatisfaction, criticism, doubt, emotion, etc**" and this is precisely why I said what I said at the beginning.  Your friend's reply is clearly nuanced.  A regular, non-nuanced reply would have been along the lines of:

> 「（ええ、）持ってますよ。」

The difference between that and the actual reply you received is huge.

What one could still not tell is exactly why s/he replied that way.  To analyze it, we might need to read the entire conversation that took place, which I will not ask you to show us.  As a native speaker, I could just almost hear the silent 「なんでそんな（当たり前の）こと聞くの？」.

Comment: Your native ears are pretty good. My friend literally later said having a credit card is 当たり前.